# Connection Failure between Visual Studio and Qt Using NamedPipe

Tags: c++, qt, named-pipes, qlocalsocket

I'm trying to establish communication between Visual Studio and Qt using the named pipe method. I have Visual Studio set up for transmission and when I run the Qt program, it establishes a connection to the created named pipe. Visual Studio recognizes this connection, ends its waiting, and then sends data. The transmission is successful, but Qt is not receiving the signal. Is there a solution for this issue?

**Visual studio - Host**

```
#include <iostream>

HANDLE hPipe;

  hPipe = CreateNamedPipeA("\\\\.\\pipe\\MyPipe", PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND, PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |
                            PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE, PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, 512, 512,
                            NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT, NULL);
  if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
  {
     std::cout << "Failed to create named pipe." << std::endl;
     return 1;
  }

  if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE) 
  {
     char dataToSend[] = "Hello from Visual Studio!";
     DWORD bytesWritten;
     WriteFile(hPipe, dataToSend, sizeof(dataToSend), &bytesWritten, NULL);
     std::cerr << "Connect to named pipe." << std::endl;
     CloseHandle(hPipe);
  }
  else 
  {
     std::cerr << "Failed to connect named pipe." << std::endl;
  }
```

**Qt - Client**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <windows.h>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSocketNotifier>

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_connect_clicked()
{
    setupNamedPipe();
}

void MainWindow::setupNamedPipe()
{
    HANDLE hPipe = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\pipe\\MyPipe", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    notifier = new QSocketNotifier((int)(intptr_t)hPipe, QSocketNotifier::Read, this);

    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {

        qDebug() << "connect to open named pipe.";
        QObject::connect(notifier, &QSocketNotifier::activated, this, &MainWindow::onPipeDataAvailable);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Failed to open named pipe.";
    }
}

void MainWindow::onPipeDataAvailable(int fd, QSocketNotifier::Type type)
{
    Q_UNUSED(type);

    HANDLE hPipe = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(intptr_t(fd));

    char buffer[256];
    DWORD bytesRead;

    if (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead, NULL))
    {
        buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
        qDebug() << "Received data from Visual Studio: " << QString::fromUtf8(buffer);
    }
}
```

If you don't understand the question, please provide feedback.

Comment: Why not use the actual Qt function to read ? See here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39002837/20213170

Comment: @nick It seems that the QLocalSocket library is not supported in my Qt

Comment: QLocalSocket is available in [Qt5](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalsocket.html) and [Qt6](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlocalsocket.html) so either you use an ancient Qt library or doing something wrong. I would guess [QSocketNotifier](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsocketnotifier.html#details) can not watch for windows file handles.